# Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'completer7'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-http

I am trying to use the below library:

https://pub.dev/packages/http

called http

when I am trying to run the code on web, I found the below error:

Compiler message:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
main.dart:1
/C:/Users/ashra/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-1.1.0/lib/src/browser_client.dart:79:7: Error: The getter 'completer7' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
- 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('/C:/Users/ashra/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-1.1.0/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
browser_client.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'completer7'.
      completer7.completeError(
      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Hi bro. Can you post some code??

Comment: You somehow accidentally edited the code in your package cache and introduced a typo.  Run `dart pub cache repair`/`flutter pub cache repair`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance it's because you not using the latest version of flutter.
You can update by running:

```
flutter upgrade
```

I ran into the same issue when the package syncfusion_flutter_sliders was added to my Flutter project and fixed it that way.

However, as mentioned above, it could also be caused by accidentally editing something you shouldn't have. But if you're sure you haven't done any as such, `flutter upgrade` should probably work.
Hope it helps